# Where can I find fence panels with 4" pickets?

Tags: wood, fence

We had some work done on a tricky part of our fence last year. We hired a professional to install the corner and the gate with the plan of extending the rest of the fence as we could afford it. He installed panels with 4" pickets.

Unfortunately now that company went out of business. We looked into DIY but the fence panels pre-made at the local home center had pickets that were too wide. I called another professional and their pickets were 5.5" wide. I'd like to make the fence uniform if possible. We have roughly 32 ft of fence that needs to be installed.

Comment: This sounds like a shopping question, which is off-topic. I'd simply buy 1x6 pickets and run them through a table saw.

Comment: Sounds like a woodworking question.